# MySql union Error in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, union

I have to fetch values from two tables, I have wrote separate query for fetching from both tables. and both queries worked properly. but I need to get this in one result object. so that I have joined queries using UNION operator. but it throws some error. the query is given below

```
       $query1 = "SELECT dev_members.name,dev_members.id,dev_members.age,dev_members.family_id,dev_family.house_name,dev_ib_account_registration.account_id FROM (dev_members) 
            JOIN dev_family ON dev_family.id=dev_members.family_id
            JOIN dev_ib_account_registration ON dev_ib_account_registration.member_id=dev_members.id 

            UNION 

            SELECT dev_members.name,dev_members.id,dev_members.age,dev_members.family_id, dev_family.
            house_name,dev_ib_sub_member_registration.account_id FROM (dev_members) 
            JOIN dev_family  ON dev_family.id=dev_members.family_id
            JOIN dev_ib_sub_member_registration ON dev_ib_sub_member_registration.member_id=dev_members.id";

            $result = $this->db->query($query);
             return $result->result();
```

and the error is:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JOIN dev_family ON dev_family.id=dev_members.family_id JOIN dev_ib_s' at line 8

Comment: Have you tried wrapping each select statement in parentheses?

Comment: When you debug the query with codeigniter what's been sent to Mysql? Have you checked if it's the same as you wrote?

Comment: @ChrisMcKnight yes , but not working

Comment: @medina yea , I have checked the same query, and error shows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something wired with the usage of brackets in your second  query

```
(dev_members) <---
```

when i use your query without them in [**Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/35566) query works ,but using with brackets it produces syntax error ,so try them without `()`

updated query

```
SELECT 
  dev_members.name,
  dev_members.id,
  dev_members.age,
  dev_members.family_id,
  dev_family.house_name,
  dev_ib_account_registration.account_id 
FROM
  dev_members
  JOIN dev_family 
    ON dev_family.id = dev_members.family_id 
  JOIN dev_ib_account_registration 
    ON dev_ib_account_registration.member_id = dev_members.id 
UNION
SELECT 
  dev_members.name,
  dev_members.id,
  dev_members.age,
  dev_members.family_id,
  dev_family.house_name,
  dev_ib_sub_member_registration.account_id 
FROM
  dev_members  
  JOIN dev_family 
    ON dev_family.id = dev_members.family_id 
  JOIN dev_ib_sub_member_registration 
    ON dev_ib_sub_member_registration.member_id = dev_members.id
```

Comment: can you paste that query here ?